How to make sure that the cable does not pass through the object?
I have little experience in blender.
I don't understand how I can make sure that the cable doesn't go through the boom.
The cable is attached to the boom, when lifting the cable should be in this position: 
In the non-raised position, the following happens:

When adding vertices to a curve, the following happens:



Yeah, if you parent geo to bones and then add new geo after the fact it can have unpredictable results at times. Just adjust your rig/model or start over with a fresh set of weighted groups and parent relationships. That's one of the hard parts about rigging is making sure your model is set up correctly to be rigged in the first place.

In my example, I created a copy of the bone.010 (named Tracker), added a Damped track (targeting bone.009) and a limit rotation bone constraints.
Then select Empty.002, shift select the armature, go to pose mode, press Ctrl P > Bone.


Thank you so much, you helped me.
